# how to include a variable in tinydb query in python?

Tags: python, database, tinydb

```
from tinydb import TinyDB, Query
db = TinyDB('db.json')
ddd = Query()
kl = free
output = db.search(ddd.state == 'free')
```

How to use variable **k1** in tinydb db.search?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use it in `db.search`

```
from tinydb import TinyDB, Query
db = TinyDB('db.json')
ddd = Query()
db.insert({'state': 'free', 'field': 1})
db.insert({'state': 'n', 'field': 2})
db.insert({'state': 'free', 'field': 3})
kl = 'free'
output = db.search(ddd.state == kl)
print(output)
```

output

```
[{'state': 'free', 'field': 1}, {'state': 'free', 'field': 3}]
```

Comment: thank you! .. can you let me know how to list the output in list or column format ?